# Как выдать 404 в дублях страниц Codeigniter 3?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Структура сайта такая:

site.ru/users/ — список пользователей
site.ru/users/user/2 — пользователь с ID2

Если после ID, я поставлю слеш (/) и допишу любое значение, то открывается также эта страница. Пример:

**site.ru/users/user/2/**

site.ru/users/user/2/dasd

site.ru/users/user/2/dasd/dasd

site.ru/users/user/2/dasd/dasd/dasd

При открытии любой ссылки открывается содержание страницы - site.ru/users/user/2/, т.е. фактически имеем дубли страниц.

Тоже самое и в статьях (можно даже без слеша подставить любое значение):

**site.ru/articles/articles-title**

site.ru/articles/articles-title/dasd

site.ru/articles/articles-titledasd

site.ru/articles/articles-titledasd/dasd

site.ru/articles/articles-title/dasd/dasd

и т.д.

Что можно сделать чтобы при открытии таких страниц отдавалась 404 ошибка?
Т.е. если открыл страницу site.ru/users/user/2, она отдает содержание. Если открыл страницу site.ru/users/user/2/xxx выдает 404 ошибку.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Методом тыка получилось решить так:

В файл routes.php добавил следующее:

```
$route['users/user/(:num)(:any)'] = '404_override';
```

Теперь если в конце ссылки вставить несуществующие данные, отдает 404 ошибку

site.ru/users/user/2/ — ОК

site.ru/users/user/2/dasd — 404

Answer (score 0):

Могу где то ошибаться, но вообще можно на php отловить это так:

```
$url=parse_url($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
$path=$url["path"];
$patharray=explode("/", $path);
if (($patharray[0]=="users") and (count($patharray>=4)) or  ($patharray[0]=="articles") and (count($patharray>=3)))
{
     header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');
     //код 404 страницы
     exit();
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Немного сюда не подходит, но возьму на заметку.